# How do I say "misunderstood" in French?

Tags: vocabulaire, traduction, anglais

I want to say

> When you text someone instead of speaking to them, it is easy to be misunderstood, and you could offend the other person.

How would I say this?

Comment: Welcome to FL Élise. We do not use "Thank you" and "xxx" when asking a question on SE. "xxx" never at all.

Comment: When asking a question you are expected to say what you have found by yourself so far, for example if you have looked in a dictionary what deos it say? In short, do not ask for a translation.

Comment: To repeat what Laure said, the French Language & Usage Stack Exchange is not a translation service! It's to help you understand things you're having trouble figuring out on your own.

Answer (score 5):

> «D'être mal compris»

Is "to be misunderstood".  Voir le verbe *comprendre* [II.2.a](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/comprendre)

Comment: Micromégas! Great story.

Comment: Pouvez-vous svp. préciser... II.2.a ?? Vous voulez dire II.A.2.a) ? Si oui, dans la rubrique syntagme ? le cas échéant quel élément ? J'aimerais comprendre le lien que vous faites... Merci !

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question in your title and given the context of the situation you are describing, the appropriate translation of "**misunderstood**" is "**mal interprété**".

As for your sentence, on way to go would be, for example:

> Les communications écrites, contrairement aux communications orales, peuvent être facilement **mal interprétées** et sont susceptibles d'offenser leurs destinataires.

Comment: This is very formal and might not fit any situation.

Answer (score 0):

"Mal compris" and "incompris" are the two most plausible translations. "Il est facile d'être mal compris" is better (because "incompris" is more formal).

Answer (score 0):

`I misunderstood.` can be

```
Je n'ai pas compris.
J'ai mal compris.
Je me suis mépris (formal)
```

`misunderstood` (adjective) can be

```
mal compris
incompris
mécompris (formal)
```

The Micromégas answer seems to be the best to me

```
D'être mal compris
```

Answer (score 0):

One could use for instance [Deepl](https://www.deepl.com/fr/translator) for translations like this and then posing here a question for a specific subject.

> Lorsque vous envoyez un message texte à quelqu'un au lieu de lui parler, il est facile d'être mal compris, et vous pourriez offenser l'autre personne.

Depending on the context, pronoun you could be replaced by on

> Lorsqu'on envoie un message texte à quelqu'un au lieu de lui parler, il est facile d'être mal compris, et on pourrait offenser l'autre personne.